Lift of a proper codimension 1 submanifold in its universal cover is collared
I encountered a statement about manifold, but I am not very familiar with it. I'd appreciate it if anyone would like to explain or give me some references! Here is the statement:

Let $M$ be a manifold and let $N\subset M$ be a proper submanifold of
codimension 1. Let $\tilde{M}$ be the universal covering of $M$ and
let $\tilde{N}\subset\tilde{M}$ be the preimage of $N$. Then we have
$\tilde{N}$ is collared in $\tilde{M}$.

One example I had in my mind is the orientable closed genus two surface $S_2$ with Poincare disk as its universal covering. Pick a separating curve $\gamma$ as a codimension 1 submanifold, the lifts are collared in the Poincare disk. However, I have no idea on how to show it in general.

A more general fact that is useful here is that every codimension 1 submanifold of a simply connected manifold (which must be orientable) is orientable. A proof of this fact can be found here.

Hi @Frank, thanks for your response! May I ask how does the orientability relate to my question?

If a codimension one submanifold is orientable, then it admits a collar neighborhood. One way to see this is to use a Riemannian metric to define an outward-pointing vector field which trivializes the normal bundle. Another way to see this is to write $TM|_N = TN \oplus \mathcal{N}$ (where $\mathcal{N}$ is the normal bundle) and to note that $\mathcal{N}$ is orientable (hence trivial) since $TN$ is.
